# Intentionally slow chart drawing using nvd3 for time-lapse video

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to produce regular line chart where data from a device is logged into a database every 10 seconds and then fetched to produce a chart.

Now I'm making a movie and using a time-lapse shooting I've made a 24 hour video of the operation which is packed into a 3 minute long clip.

Now I want to draw the chart using the stored data so that it will match video in speed and will be timed precisely. Namely, I want to draw 24h of data in 3 minutes on the chart. I'll then use video editor to overlay it over the video.

Which property or properties, or callback should I use?

P.s. As I'm using nvd3 to draw charts on site, I'd prefer using slightly modified code for the video. But if that's impossible to do with nvd3, please, make a kind suggestion which charting package you advise to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, so you have a slowdown factor of 24 hours / 3 minutes = 480. For a 10 second interval, that means about 21 milliseconds. You're not going to get that kind of precision with Javascript timers running in a browser.

Comment: 21 milliseconds per point. The problem I can't figure how in principle to get the slowdown. 
But thanks for the comment, I'll probably  have to do smaller slowdown factor and then use video editor to speed up.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to create the "frames" of the graph animation individually and then make a video of that. That's the only way you're going to get precise timing.

Comment: Basically, yes, but how do I do that with nvd3? Looks like I'd rather do that in Python or C++ which sounds weird to me...

Comment: That sounds like a better approach. Not sure if you could do that easily with NVD3.